# Unable to open Excel file with xlsread in Matlab

Tags: excel, matlab

Tyring to run [SHPB analysis tool](https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/50921-split-hopkinson-pressure-bar-graphical-analysis-tool) from MATLAB file exchange site, the program reads an Excel file with 2 columns.

```
% import call (this is usually time consuming)
voltages = xlsread(target_filename);
```

Although I have provided a one row, two column file (1,2), the program receives exception as below

```
>> SHPB_Analysis_Tool
1864 voltages = xlsread(target_filename);
Error using xlsread (line 260)
Error: The server threw an exception.



Error in SHPB_Analysis_Tool>excel_vg_auto_Callback (line 1864)
voltages = xlsread(target_filename);

Error in gui_mainfcn (line 95)
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in SHPB_Analysis_Tool (line 42)
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in
matlab.graphics.internal.figfile.FigFile/read>@(hObject,eventdata)SHPB_Analysis_Tool('excel_vg_auto_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject)) 
Error while evaluating Menu Callback.
```

As you can see in the picture, the file path is valid.
[image]

Matlab is 2018a and Excel is 2016.

Any idea to debug more?

I even tried to create a simple test code like this to open an Excel file

```
uiwait(msgbox('Using this import feature: When Excel Loads, highlight data in adjacent columns.'))
dialog_title = 'Select Excel File. When Excel Loads, highlight data in adjacent columns.'; % use tag w/o "_" as popup window title
[file_name, file_path] = uigetfile('*.xl*', dialog_title);
target_filename        = fullfile(file_path,file_name);
voltages = xlsread(target_filename);
[~, n] = size(voltages);
```

As you can see in the picture, the function fails again.

[image]

Any thought?

Comment: I frequently have the same problem everytime another program automatically install an add-in for Excel. The resolution is described here in [matlab central](https://mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/291601-error-the-server-threw-an-exception-in-desktop)

Comment: Thank you. In fact disabling "COM add-in" fixed that.